# SSIS : how to convert the source column from ID to Value

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm creating a SSIS package to load data from a CSV file to SQL table. The sample CSV file is

```
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,DEPT_ID,MANAGER_ID,SALARY
1801,SCOTT,20,1221,3000
1802,ALLEN,30,1221,3400
```

I need to load data into a SQL Server table, but while loading I need to load `Department Name` and `Manager Name` instead of their `ID`s. So I need to convert the CSV source to

```
1801,SCOTT,FINANCE,JOHNSON,3000
1802,ALLEN,HR,JOHNSON,3400
```

The values for `Department Name` and `Manager name` come from the SQL Server database only. But how do I query and convert ID to text values?

I'm new to SSIS, please suggest how can I achieve this.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsert]            
    (            
   -- Declare Parameters here for your CSV file   


    )            
    AS            
    BEGIN            
    SET NOCOUNT ON;            

    declare @query varchar(max)            


    CREATE TABLE #TEMP            
    (            
    [FieldName] [int] NOT NULL ,          
    [FieldName] int NOT NULL,          
    )            


    SET @query = 'BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM ''' + PathOfYourTextFile + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'            
    --print @query            
    --return            
    execute(@query)            


    BEGIN TRAN;            

    MERGE TableName AS Target 
    -- Now here you can get the value Department Name and Manager Name by using Target.Id --in the table from where you mant to get the value of the Manager Name            
    USING (SELECT * FROM #TEMP) AS Source            
    ON (Target.YourTableId = Source.YourTextFileFieldId)
    -- In the above line we are checking if the particular row exists in the table(Table1)  then update the Table1 if not then insert the new row in Table-1.           

    WHEN MATCHED THEN            
    UPDATE SET             
    Target.SomeId= Source.SomeId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN            

    -- Insert statement
```

The above code is just an example for you by taking the help from this you can edit in your code. And one more important thing for you, Bulk Insert is one of the great way to save the CSV files. So try to use this..:)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, however the actual requirement is different and i need to use a SSIS package. I hoped that an easier example would better explain the requirement. so i gave that example. Please tell me how can i achieve this using SSIS package. While processing the source data i need to replace the ID with the text value from database and move to the target table.

Comment: In the end i used the bulk insert which much easier than using a pakage

Answer (score 1):

In SSIS package from Data Flow tab use LOOKUP process from the Toolbox. You'll specify the table to get your string values from and which columns to use for the join and the column to substitue your IDs with.